# Error: near "FROM": syntax error - SQL code

Tags: sql, r

```
dt1_a <- sqldf("

SELECT Brand, Year,
sum(SalesQuantity) AS sumQSales,
avg(SalesPrice) AS avgPrice
FROM tSales GROUP BY Brand

")

str(dt1_a)
```

Comment: What is the error exactly? Just near From??

Comment: what type of database are you connecting to? looks like `sqldf` is an [R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My guess given just the query is that you are not grouping enough variables.

When you have aggregating functions in your query (`sum` and `avg` in this case), all other variables may need to be included in the `group by` query. (@G.Grothendieck advised that it is not always necessary. Since I've never been able to get it to work without, I must have stopped trying before finding the exception. Thanks!)

Try this:

```r
dt1_a <- sqldf("

SELECT Brand, Year,
sum(SalesQuantity) AS sumQSales,
avg(SalesPrice) AS avgPrice
FROM tSales GROUP BY Brand, Year

")
```

Comment: That was actually the code for the second part of my question! thank you!

Comment: It is not true that you must include all aggregating variables.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, okay, I'll adjust the answer, thanks for the feedback. Everything I've done with queries fails when I have an aggregating function (e.g., `sum`) and not group the other variables, is there an example where `SELECT Year, sum(SalesQuantity)` will work with no grouping (besides 1 row, perhaps not even then)?

Comment: I've usually get an error like "you must include X in the group by statement" when that is required. since it is saying "near FROM" I would think there is an issue with the select, like a punctuation issue, missing comma, unclosed curly brace or something like that

Comment: Try `sqldf("select Type, sum(uptake), sum(conc) from CO2 group by Type, Treatment")` where CO2 comes with R.

Comment: That query groups on all variables not aggregated (and another). My point (perhaps mis-stated) was that any variable in the query not being aggregated should be in a "group by" (though more may be provided). Perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: That isn't true either. This does not give an error: `sqldf("select Type, sum(uptake), sum(conc) from CO2 group by  Treatment")`

Comment: Very interesting, many of my assumptions are being shattered/redefined. Okay, so I just tested: with that query, SQL Server complains with `Column 'CO2.Type' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`, so my statement is heavily based on SQL Server and not on SQL itself. Thanks.

Comment: SQLite is not SQL Server.

Comment: Interesting differences between DBMSes, I had thought that "group by" was more universal: the truncated query fails in sql server and postgresql, but passes in sqlite and mariadb, though the method of choosing non-aggregate-column values seems arbitrary. Okay, so it is not a requirement, do you have any suggestions on when it makes sense to intentionally leave a non-aggregated column out of the "group by"? Since the value chosen is likely something like "first value in the filtered group", I can't help but think that the value is unreliable.